# How do I rollback a SQLite DB when iPhone application quits while or during inserting data into table?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am using SQLite (without any external library) for my iPhone app. I have huge data of nearly 500 rows (coming from web services so it cannot be inserted manually from sqlite manager) to be inserted into a SQLite table.
I checked the logs and insert is executed successfully.

```
if ( sqlite3_exec(database, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
```

But when the app is quit in the middle of insert operation, only some rows get inserted, for example say 200. Thus is there a way to do a complete rollback when the application quits in the midde of insert operation? 
  Thus when I restart the application, I am reading only 200 rows.

Note: I am using NSOperationQueue and thus my app runs without any glitch during insertion (which takes nearly 20 secs for whole insert)

Is there a reference tutorial for this case to avoid incomplete insertion into SQLite?
I know that I may have to use transaction for this but is there any good ref?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned not adding any libraries. If I recall sqlite3 has a library. Did you at least link that?

Comment: @stunner could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Note: i have added libsqlite3.dylib and all normal sql operations are working fine

Comment: On the left side of each answer to any question, there is an up arrow and down arrow used for voting on the question. Below the down arrow there is a check mark that should be selected when an answer has  adequately answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just start transaction and end. Simple case:

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

... (your insert code)

sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: but how sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0); be executed if app is quit in between of insert operation, do i have to rollback the operation?

Comment: Is their a complete refernce of managing multiple inserts in sqlite table, i am using transaction "BEGIN" (before insert) and "COMMIT" (after all insert statments) but still only some records are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully i found the way out:

```
if ([db_handle openConnectionSucess]==1 && (sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0))==SQLITE_OK) {  

      char *error;

         NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into StationTbl (id, name, address) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%f\", \"%f\")",id,name,value];
        if ( sqlite3_exec(database, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
        {


        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
        }

      if(sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0) ==SQLITE_OK){

      }
      else {
          sqlite3_exec(database, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);
      }
}
```

It is solving 2 purpose:

1. the insert is executed in 3 secs max (as comp to 25 secs without
   using transactions
2. it is auto rollbacked if app is quit .

Thank all who made an effort in the post!!

Comment: This is exactly what I answered. Please accept if you don't mind :-)